# my segue is not working in imagepicker

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, segue, uiimagepickercontroller

I have an `UIImagePickerController` so when user choose his/her photo the segue is performed but segue is not working ( actually is working but the vc is not loaded ) this is my code:

```
        let imagepicker = UIImagePickerController()

        imagepicker.delegate = self

        imagepicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary

        imagepicker.allowsEditing = true

        self.present(imagepicker, animated: true)
        //...
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
            takenimage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("image loaded")
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToPrescriptionView", sender: nil)
        }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
          if segue.identifier == "ToPrescriptionView" {
          let PrescriptionView = segue.destination as! Prescription
          PrescriptionView.PrescriptionImage = takenimage
         print("segue loaded")
        }
```

I'm getting "image loaded" and "segue loaded" but my viewcontroller remains previous one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to `performSegue` inside completion block of `dismiss` when you dismissing `UIImagePickerController`.

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "ToPrescriptionView", sender: nil)
}
```